# Mysql "Unknown column 'slon–dlon' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql-function

I have the following 'haversin' algorithm implemented as an SQL function.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `db`.`haversin` (slat FLOAT, slon FLOAT, dlat FLOAT, dlon FLOAT) 
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
 declare alphaLon,a FLOAT;
 set alphaLon=(slon–dlon);
 set a=3956*2*ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((slat - abs(dlat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(slat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dlat) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((alphaLon) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) ));
 return a;
 END 
//delimiter;
```

when executing the above, i get a 1064 error 'syntax error near //delimiter', however, the function DOES get created.

what's confusing the most, when running the function, thats the result:

```
mysql> SELECT haversin(2.0,45.0,2.0,1.2);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'slon–dlon' in 'field list'
```

how is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The code you have pasted contains three instructions to your MySQL client:

   1. Change its statement delimiter to `//`;
   2. Send to the server a `CREATE FUNCTION` command; and
   3. An unknown instruction `delimiter;`.

   Thus the first two commands succeed and the third fails.  To rectify the failure of the third command, insert whitespace between the `delimiter` keyword and the desired new delimiter.
2. Stored programs are not evaluated until they are executed: thus runtime errors (such as "unknown column") will not be detected until the function is invoked.  Indeed, this makes perfect sense given that the database schema could change after a function is defined.

   You are receiving this error because your minus character is in fact an [EN DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/) (U+2013).  For arithmetic subtraction, replace with [HYPHEN-MINUS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002d/) (U+002D).